# Preserve username nsstring after app exit

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

What would you consider the proper way of storing a simple username string in your app, so that it is there when you open the app again? I've been reading of a couple of ways to do so: core data, plist, nsuserdefaults.

What are some of the ways people are using to do this, and if possible pros and cons of the proposed way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Data is serialized into SQLite, and makes more sense for when you're dealing with many objects and dynamically creating/deleting them.

Plists fall somewhere between the complexity of Core Data and NSUserDefaults. They can handle data with some structure, and are saved as a file on the filesystem.

Since you're just dealing with one piece of information, NSUserDefaults makes the most sense for you. All you have to do to save a string is:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:userNameString forKey:@"UserName"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

Then, to retrieve the string:

```
NSString *userName = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"UserName"];
```

Comment: Thanks for the details. Definitely sounds like the simplicity of information I'm storing calls for NSUserDefaults. I have worked with CoreData, but thought it was like bringing a bazooka to kill a fly. Just wanted to get input from you guys.

Answer (score 3):

I think NSUserDefaults would be the right choice here. It's there for storing the user's default settings, which is exactly what you describe. In addition, it is very easy to access from your code.

Answer (score 3):

NSUserDefaults is OK. However, I guess that if you have a user name, you also have a password to log in, don't you? In such case, why don't you use Keychain then to save it?

Comment: I will not be storing the password. The devices will more than likely be shared among many people. The only reason why I would consider storing an encrypted password would be if lack of connectivity on login should be covered. Fortunately web services authentication is part of the requirements.

Comment: so I think that NSUserDefaults would be the most appropriate in your case. I have used it several times in a similar context in the app and by now I cannot tell if there is any better solution for what you need.

Answer (score 1):

NSUserDefaults is the best (in my opinion). However you could also use archiving if you decided not to use it.

That said if you use a UIDocument you can link it to the cloud if you what the usernames to be synchronised over different apps.